# Log of time series evaluated

Tags: finance

I'm new to Mathematica and am trying to plot log-returns of a stock as a timeseries object. However, the following code gives me back elements of the form "Log[151.23$]" unevaluated. What am I doing wrong?

```
Differences[Log[FinancialData["GE", {2018, 1, 1}, "All"]]]
```

I know you can get it to work if you use the "values" of the time series, but this removes the dates and I need them for a DateListPlot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QuantityMagnitude` command does the work.

```
ts = Differences[Log[QuantityMagnitude[FinancialData["GE", {2018, 1, 1}, "All"]]]]
DateListPlot[ts]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: As returns, technically they should be plotted as a histogram.  By contrast, a time series (index) makes sense as a line plot.

Comment: It's interesting how your answer is working with time series. Some unobvious semantics going on, such as `Log` knows not to operate on the dates.  Seems quite specific and a bit black box.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = FinancialData["GE", {2018, 1, 1}, "All"];
b = Normal[a];

DateListPlot[Transpose[{b[[2 ;;, 1]],
   Differences@Log[b[[All, 2, 1]]]}], Joined -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

alternatively

```
a = FinancialData["GE", {2018, 1, 1}, "All"];
b = Normal[a];

c = Rest@b[[All, 1, 1, ;; 3]];
d = Differences@Log[b[[All, 2, 1]]];
DateListPlot[Transpose[{c, d}], Joined -> False]
```

note

```
b[[All, 2, 1]] == QuantityMagnitude@b[[All, 2]]
```

> True